# Particle system not copy object with particle system?

Tags: unity, particles

[image]
"main karma" is an object with three particles. "Karma particle system" is a particle system copy "main karma" object without particle system inside it ?!! how to copy object with the particle system ?

Comment: Note that the editor only simulates the particle systems of the object you have selected. When you create multiple copies of an object with a particle system component, those will only render in play mode or when you select them.

Comment: which mean, this will not work ?

Comment: Of course it will work. It just won't show the particles in the editor window.